# How to add TextView dynamically to ListView

Tags: android

Actually, in my app I want to insert `TextView` in the `ListView` dynamically but how can I do it? I don't have any idea. I am sending my code where I use `textView` which I want to insert in the `ListView` dynamically. Can anyone please suggest it to me? If possible with examples.

**My current code:**

```
public void displayHistory()
{

        int iHistCount = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryCount();
        String strDisplay;
        int i;
        boolean bStarred = false;

        SimpleDateFormat sdFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");

        for (i=0; i<iHistCount; i++)
        {
                strDisplay = "";

                Date dtHist = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryDate(i);

                strDisplay=sdFormatter.format(dtHist.getTime());

                LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayoutHist1);

                LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);

                LinearLayout rowLayout=new LinearLayout(this) ;

                layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);

                TextView tTextHistory1=new TextView(this);
                tTextHistory1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tTextHistory1.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);
                tTextHistory1.setText(strDisplay);

                rowLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.history_scroll_label_bg);
                rowLayout.addView(tTextHistory1,param);

                strDisplay=" ";

                if (i == 0)
                       if (CycleManager.getSingletonObject().isCycleStopped())
                               strDisplay = "Stopped";
                       else
                               strDisplay = "In progress";
                else
                {
                         Date dtNextHist = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryDate(i-1);
                         long lDiff =dtNextHist.getTime()-dtHist.getTime();
                         lDiff=lDiff/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

                         strDisplay=Long.toString(lDiff);

                         if (lDiff<DeclareVariable.CYCLE_MIN_LENGTH || lDiff>DeclareVariable.CYCLE_MAX_LENGTH)
                         {
                                 strDisplay=strDisplay+"*";
                                 bStarred = true;
                         }
                 }

                TextView tTextHistory2=new TextView(this);
                tTextHistory2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tTextHistory2.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);
                tTextHistory2.setText(strDisplay);
                rowLayout.addView(tTextHistory2,param);  

        }
        strDisplay=" ";
        if (bStarred)
                strDisplay="* Shorter or longer than accepted";
        else
                strDisplay=" ";

        TextView tTextHistory3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewHeading);
        tTextHistory3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        tTextHistory3.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);
        tTextHistory3.setText(strDisplay);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you are asking, but if you want to add things from a datasource you need to add a ListAdapter, which allows the list to populate from a datasource. The best way to do this is with an inflater. Below is some code I am using for my Android app that fetches data from a URL and populates it. Let me know if you need more clarification!

Here's a link to a tutorial as well: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

```
public class CheckinList extends ListActivity {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final ListView list = getListView();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CheckinItem>(this, R.layout.checkin_item, main.Crunch) {
                  @Override
                  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                      View row;
                      if (null == convertView) {
                            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkin_item, null);
                        } else {
                            row = convertView;
                        }
                      TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
                      name.setText(getItem(position).getVenueName());
                      TextView time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time);
                      time.setText(getItem(position).getTime().toString());
                      TextView address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.address);
                      address.setText(getItem(position).getAddress());
                      TextView crossStreet = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.crossStreet);
                      if(getItem(position).getCrossStreet() != ""){
                          address.append(", ");
                          crossStreet.setText(getItem(position).getCrossStreet());
                      }
                      return row;
                  }
              });
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually in my app in the String variable ie strDisplay whenever i change the date in the calender it take the date and stored in strDisplay..now what i what is to insert this Strdisplay value in my listview..moreever when the user enter new date than it insert the new date in the listView without overriding the previous date present in the list view.. so please suggest me how that can be done in my code..i have no idea about it

Comment: sounds like you are trying to add another string (i.e. row) to an already existing list? I would create an arrayList or something and then add the string to the arraylist. Then you could populate the list from the arraylist using an arrayadapter

Comment: yeh thats what i want..i tried a lot but cant able to do it..can you suggest me how that can be done..if possible by taking my code example

Comment: honestly I cannot really understand your code. I am assuming you know how to create an ArrayList, if you do create that with your data. Then with the line that says "list.setadapter" in my code, replace "main.Crunch" with your own arrayList. In the same line, where it says "ArrayAdapter<CheckinItem>" replace "CheckinItem" with the type you used in your ArrayList. 

The bottom (i.e.) where I have "TextViews" are just ways to take what strings I need and display them.

Comment: Actually in my code what i have done is first get the date and stored in the dtHist variable then i stored that dtHist data into strDisplay variable..after that i created a textView..then set the text of an textView with strDisplay..and placed the textView in the rowLayout..similarly when i enter another date..than the loop execute and again same process goes on and place each textView in rowlayout and in vertical arrangement..now problem is that when the amount of data increases i cant make scroll here..thats why i need a listview to store that textView