# Adding array of textviews dynamically to linear layout

Tags: android, layout, textview

I tried to add an array of textviews which i defined as a public variable, but when i run the application, it force closes as soon as it gets into for loop. This is the code:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            pairs=new TextView[num_match+1];
            for(int l=1;l<=num_match;l++)
            {
                pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
                pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
                pairs[l].setId(l);
                pairs[l].setText(m1[l]+" - "+m2[l]);
                myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
            }
```

Comment: Provide some detail like LogCat error ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create new TextViews to put into the TextView array and you are skipping the first index (`pairs[0]`) which will lead to trouble later:

```
pairs=new TextView[num_match];
for(int l=0; l<num_match; l++)
{
    pairs[l] = new TextView(this);
    pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
    pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
    pairs[l].setId(l);
    pairs[l].setText(m1[l + 1]+" - "+m2[l + 1]);
    myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
}
```

---

From your comments, I included this simple working example to help you:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView[] pairs=new TextView[4];
        for(int l=0; l<4; l++)
        {
            pairs[l] = new TextView(this);
            pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
            pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
            pairs[l].setId(l);
            pairs[l].setText((l + 1) + ": something");
            myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
        }

    }
}
```

With the layout `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: when i put pairs[l] = new TextView(this); eclipse underlines new TextView(this) and the error says:
The constructor TextView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: Ok, add your class name before `this`, for example `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: thanks, it doesn't show error now. but i then want to see that textviews in my activity, but when i set setContentView(R.Layout.activity_main) nothing happens.

Comment: i assigned id to my linear layout and called it myLayout, maybe i should call the method with that? sry for bothering so much

Comment: I added an example, I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to initailize `pairs[l]` before using it, like this:

```
    for(int l=1;l<=num_match;l++)
    {
        pairs[l] = new TextView();
        //...
    }
```

Otherwise it will have NullPointerException, and collapse as described.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? (It's not perfect, but it's basic observation is correct.)

Comment: when i put pairs[l] = new TextView(this); eclipse underlines new TextView(this) and the error says: The constructor TextView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Why have an `array of TextViews`? Can you replace it with `ListView`?

I think that would be a better way. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584906/how-to-insert-textview-dynamically-in-list-view).