# Create and add EditText widget to view on click of button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

I have a `Fragment` that inflates a `RelativeLayout` in `onCreateView()`. I have a button in the `ActionBar` that I want to add a `EditText` widget to the view each time it is clicked. I made an `ArrayList` of `EditTexts` that are added with a custom `EditText` class. How can I inflate all the `EditText` feild in the `ArrayList`? Is there a way to inflate just by referencing the index of the array. Note I eventually want to add an `OnTouchListener` to each feild.

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    private List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    private int n = 0;
    private View.OnTouchListener TouchHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_actionbar, menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.menu_item_add_text:
                n=n+1;
                editTextList.add(editText(n));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private EditText editText(int id){
        EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        editText.setId(id);
        editText.setOnTouchListener(TouchHandler);
        editTextList.add(editText);
        return editText;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment, parent, false);

        TouchHandler = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

                // .......................
        };
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to add the **edittext**'s starting from index 0??

Comment: Well I want the view to start with no EditTexts on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain one counter globally ,

```
private int counter;
```

---

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
        EditText editText = editTextList.get(counter);
        // you can add the editText to the view you want
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you:)

Comment: So I set the onclicklistener on the view and not the button?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what was suggested in the answer to this question [Adding array of textviews dynamically to linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516732/adding-array-of-textviews-dynamically-to-linear-layout).

In OnCreateView:

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pairs=new EditText[9];
    for(int l=0; l<9; l++)
    {
        pairs[l] = new EditText(getActivity() );
        pairs[l].setTextSize(15);
        pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
        pairs[l].setId(l);
        pairs[l].setText((l + 1));
        pairs[l].setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        pairs[l].setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    }
```

In onOptionsItemsSelected:

```
 private int counter;

 case R.id.menu_item_add_text:

     myLayout.addView(pairs[counter]);
     counter++;

 return true;
```